# Magento : Modify the qty of specific item in shopping cart

Tags: magento

i m developping an extension for custom price this is my code

item.php :

```
class WebDirect_CustomPrice_Model_Sales_Quote_Item 
extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item {

    public function representProduct($product) {
        $parentResult = parent::representProduct($product);

        //if parent result is already false, we already have a different product, exit.
        if ($parentResult === false) {
            return $parentResult;
        }

        $bool = "";

        $itemProduct = $this->getProduct();

        Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();       
        $customPrice = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('custom_price');

        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $productPrice = $item->getPrice();

            if($productId == $itemProduct->getId()){
                /*
                 * do our check for 'same product' here.
                * Returns true if attribute is the same thus it is hte same product
                */
                if ($productPrice == $customPrice) {
                    $bool = true; //same product
                    break;
                } else {
                    $bool = false; //different product
                }       
            }

        }return $bool;

    }




}
```

Observer :

```
class WebDirect_CustomPrice_Model_Observer {
    const MODULE_NAME = 'WebDirect_CustomPrice';
    public $test = false;
    public function convertPricespanToInput($observer = NULL) {
        if (!$observer) {
            return;
        }
        if ('product.info.simple' == $observer->getEvent()->getBlock()->getNameInLayout()) {
            if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/'.self::MODULE_NAME)) {
                $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
                $block = new WebDirect_CustomPrice_Block_priceSpanToInput();
                $block->setPassingTransport($transport['html']);
                $block->toHtml();
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function applyCustomPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        // @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item 
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            $item = $item->getParentItem();
        }

        Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

        $customPrice = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('custom_price');
        $defaultCp = $item->getProduct()->getData('min_price');

            if($customPrice >= $defaultCp){

                $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            }

    }
```

the probleme is :

1 - add product2 1000$; 2- add product2 2000$; that works fine and it looks like this :

```
         - Product2 ------ Qty: 1 ---------- total: 1000$ 
         - Product2 ------ Qty: 1 ---------- total: 2000$
```

3 - add product2 2000$; now it erase product2(1000$) and put product2 qty=2 total 4000$ (ERROR !!!!)

the cart now is :

```
         - Product2 ------ Qty: 2 ---------- total: 4000$ 
         - Product2 ------ Qty: 1 ---------- total: 2000$
```

so it should look like this :

```
     - Product2 ------ Qty: 1 ---------- total: 1000$ 
     - Product2 ------ Qty: 2 ---------- total: 4000$
```

this is an image describing the probleme :

[image]

(its the same product with different prices)

what I want is when add a product to cart and magento founds the same product with the same price it updates quantity else if its the same product with different price value then add it as different product else just add it !!!!

how to solve this ?

Comment: Please explain little bet more what you want...

Comment: @VishalSharma what I want is when add a product to cart and magento founds the same product with the same price it updates quantity else if its the same product with different price value then add it as different product else just add it !!!!